# In symony. After i added a user , how can i get that user data in DoctrineListener's postPersist method

Tags: php, symfony

Here u see, i added a new user to database, i want to do something after adding a new user, such as storing user data to redis and so on..
I am thinking `Listener` to do that .

The question is :

I got the entity in postPersist. but it's an object . I want to convert it to an array to store it.

```
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
//      var_dump($em->getRepository('AppBundle:YaUser')->find($entity->getUid()));
        if($entity instanceof YaUser){
        }
    }
```

I can't use `get_object_vars` btw. Because the `entity` is private then i get empty

THX:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the JMS Serializer

To serialize and object:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$serializer->serialize($yourObject, 'json');
```

And to deserialize:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$object = $serializer->deserialize($jsonData, 'YourNamespace\YourObject', 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my code. It looks strange.

```
if($entity instanceof YaUser) {
    $help = $this->container->get('help');

    $uinfo = [];
    foreach(get_class_methods($entity) as $k => $v) {
        if(preg_match('/^get.*$/', $v)){
            $uinfo_key = strtolower(str_replace('get', '', $v));
            $uinfo[$uinfo_key] = call_user_func_array([$entity, $v], []);
        }
    }
    if($uinfo){
        $key = $help->redisKey('uinfo').$uinfo['uid'];
        $u_old = $help->getRedis($key, $help::REDIS_ARRAY);
        $uinfo = array_merge((array)$u_old, (array)$uinfo);
        $help->saveRedis($key, $uinfo);
    }
}
```